# Django reusable app url namespace issue

Tags: python, django, namespaces, urlconf

I have a Django project, `training` and an app inside this project, `tests`. The folder structure looks like this:

```
django-training
    tests
        urls.py
    training
        urls.py
```

Inside `training/urls.py` I have this pattern defined:

```
url(r'^tests/', include('tests.urls', namespace='tests'))
```

And inside `tests/urls.py` I have these patterns defined:

```
url(r'^$', index, name='index'),
url(r'^(\d+)/$', view, name='view'),
url(r'^give-up/$', give_up, name='give_up'),
url(r'^(\d+)/result/$', result, name='result')
```

Everything works fine.

But, what if I want to package the `tests` app as a reusable app that works in any Django project? What should I do with the URL patterns?

I created a `tests/settings.py` file and changed the `ROOT_URLCONF` config var to point to `tests/urls.py`. But this won't work, as this error will arise:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/clean2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tests/tests.py", line 173, in testContext
    response = self.client.get(reverse('tests:view', args=(1,)))
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/clean2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 492, in reverse
key)
NoReverseMatch: u'tests' is not a registered namespace
```

The error is quite logic, since `reverse` needs the namespace to be defined (`tests`, that is).

My question is: how and where shall I define this namespace for the reusable app so that URLs will work independent of the Django project the app is installed in?

Comment: Can we see your reverse function call?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I've added the full traceback of the error, including the function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a quick solution to this problem in the [Django manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs).

In my `tests/urls.py` I've included the `test` namespace as so:

```
test_patterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(\d+)/$', view, name='view'),
    url(r'^give-up/$', give_up, name='give_up'),
    url(r'^(\d+)/result/$', result, name='result'),
)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^tests/', include(test_patterns, namespace='tests')),
)
```

URL reverse problems are now solved and everything works as expected.

Comment: This is what I was telling you to do. I thought you had other apps other than `tests`.

Comment: No, I didn't, and was confused about where to place that include with the namespace. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises because you are doing some testing, and this have not added `tests's` url to the main `urls.py`, this is why:

```
response = self.client.get(reverse('tests:view', args=(1,)))
```

Gives:

```
u'tests' is not a registered namespace
```

Because you have not added the `tests` package in your main `urls.py` file.

Comment: I know what the problem is, I didn't know how to solve it. Which was the main `urls.py` file if I was testing only my reusable app?

Comment: @AndreiHorak Just add your testing app to your main `urls.py`, and register it as an app, it should work fine then.

Comment: I am testing a sole reusable app, I don't understand which `urls.py` are you talking about. I installed my app package with `pip` and ran `django-admin.py test tests --settings=tests.settings`. I have no other `urls.py` than the one in `tests/urls.py`.

Comment: So, `tests` is your only app?

Comment: Yes, `tests` is the only app.